# Make a single insert query in python

Tags: python

I tried to create a single insert query for the values in `template_list` array. These values are for field `template_name`.

```
dir_template_list = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES(%s)" % (dir_template_list)
```

Is there a simple/easier way to create this query using string placeholder?

```
INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES ('template1'),('template2'),('template3')
```

**Edit:** This is my actual table structure

```
FIELD   
-------
id             int(6)         
template_name  VARCHAR(128)
```

Comment: Do you want to create one line with three columns or three lines with one column?

Comment: Are you literally only adding one row ?

Comment: @Matthias one line but insert multiple values. :)

Comment: @JonClements adding multiple rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, **NEVER use string formatting to create queries** - or you'll risk SQL injection vulnerabilities, have to deal with escaping, etc.

The proper way is to use single queries for every row and passing the data as parameters:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES (%s)"
for template in dir_template_list:
    conn.query(sql, (template,))
```

To improve the performance you might want to do this in a transaction or using a prepared statement.

Comment: can you please explain this line `query(sql, (template,))` by the way i'm using python 2.5

Comment: That's whatever method your database api contains to send a query. The first argument is the SQL statement, the second the parameters for the placeholders in your query (depending on the database it might not be `%s` but something else, e.g. `?`). Oh, and why the hell are you using such an ancient python version? You should really use 2.7 or at least 2.6...

Comment: Legacy codes, majority of our apps here are still in 2.4. An ancient traditions in our company :) for new apps we have the will to use any. In my case, i have to create a separate module from the existing.

Answer (score 2):

As ThiefMaster points out, you should never build SQL queries with string formatting using input that ever came from a user.  It's a SQL injection vulnerability, and is the #1 security problem in software systems today.

Your database provides a method to supply a query string and data separately which is safe, and you should use it:

```
dir_template_list = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
conn.execute(sql, *dir_template_list)
```

Note: I don't know what your database connection is called, but `conn` is common. Also, different databases use different syntax for the placeholders:  `?` and `%s` are both possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If it's one line with 3 columns the code should be something like this (provided the table exists):

```
import sqlite3
dir_template_list = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
con.execute(sql, dir_template_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my answer is:

```
from itertools import repeat
valqs = ','.join(repeat('%s', len(dir_template_list)))
sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES(%s)" % valqs
```

Then on your cursor/connection object execute(sql, dir_template_list).

Comment: @islandmyth So you're moving the goal post arounds a bit aren't you? So you have an ID column with a single string?

Comment: i used to do that in my database structure. If you noticed the SQL query in my question, that is the query that i want to achieve actually.

Comment: about the id, it's `auto-increment`

Comment: @islandmyth fine about the auto int - is it, or is it not a varchar string that you're trying to put a `repr()` of a tuple to? ie, the DB table contains *exactly* two columns...?

Comment: exactly contains two columns. I manage to achieve the query but not aesthetically: `string_holder = "('" + "'),('".join(dir_template_list)+ "')"
    sql = "INSERT INTO tbltemplate (template_name) VALUES%s" % (string_holder)`